# Cmdlet fails when using pipeline

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I'm making a module for my company, where we doing common task with PowerShell.
One of the things is to set mailbox permissions and AD permissions on a shared mailbox with just one cmdlet.

My cmdlet is called `Add-NxMailboxPermission` and takes the 3 parameters `$Identity`, `$User` and `$AutoMapping` and accepts pipeline input on $ Identity

If I call the cmdlet as follows:

```
Add-NxMailboxPermission -Identity (Get-Mailbox -Identity <mailbox>) -User <user>
```

it works fine. If I use pipeline as follows:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity <mailbox> | Add-NxMailboxPermission -User <user>
```

only the `Add-ADPermission` part of the cmdlet is executed. No error is generated, but no Mailbox Permission is set.

I think that maybe its param `$Identity` that I defined as `[string[]]` but `Add-MailboxPermission` accepts mailboxidparameter as its Identity parameter.

My cmdlet look likes this:

```
function Add-NxMailboxPermission {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
       [string[]] $Identity,

       [Parameter(Mandatory)]
       [string]   $User,

       [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
       [switch]   $AutoMapping = $true
    )

    process {
        foreach ($i in $identity) {
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$i for $user", "Setting mailbox permission ('FullAccess')")) {
                try {
                    Write-Verbose "Setting mailbox permission on $i for $user"
                    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $i -User $User -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping:$AutoMapping -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop

                    Write-Verbose "Setting ADPermission on $i for $user"
                    Add-ADPermission -Identity $i -User $User -Extendedrights "Send As" -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
                } catch {
                    Write-Warning "Can not set permission on $i for $user"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change line 8 to:

```
[Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter[]] $Identity
```

As the same type as `Get-MailBox` return, then I get this error:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter].
At line:8 char:14
+ ...             [Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParamete ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Excha...lboxIdParameter:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: Change the type of `$Identity` to `[Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter]`

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages in comments, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41419178/edit) the original question instead. I meant `[Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter[]]` above, if that helps

Comment: I have try to do so, bu got this error: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter]

Comment: Only works when the Exchange snap-in has been loaded (or you're connected to a remote Exchange session)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, and I’m connected to a remote Exchange session. Still got the error when I try that approach

Comment: I would request you to post the error screenshot if possible.

Comment: I don't have an Exchange server at my disposal, but I would suspect that you need to load the Exchange PowerShell snapin or module for that type to become available (see Mathias' 3rd comment). From what I've read you need to install the management tools from the Exchange installation media.